# Migrate SQLite windows forms app to universal windows app (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, windows-10-universal

I made a windows forms app that connects to locally created SQLite db. It's a pretty simple app, that mainly does selecting and inserting into database.
I had a class that checked if such database exists and if not, it created it. I also added some methods for executing queries and such.

Now, in windows forms (or in console app) the connection was pretty simple:

```
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=sampleDB.sqlite;Version=3;");
    conn.Open();
    //Assume that i created table Person(int ID, string NAME)
    string sql = "select * from Person";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read()){
        Console.WriteLine(reader["ID"] + " | " + reader["NAME"]);
    }
    conn.Close();
```

Now, I tried migrating my app from **Windows Forms** to **Universal Windows App**.
First thing I did, I saw that **System.Data.SQLite.dll** is not valid for such app and so I installed **SQLite for Universal Windows Platform**, together with **SQLite.Net-PCL**

But the problem is now that I don't know how to pass queries as string as I did before.
All I encountered was that I had to create class Person with Id and Name as attributes, and then write something like this:

```
    SQLitePlatformWinRT sqlitePlatform = new SQLitePlatformWinRT();
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(sqlitePlatform, "sampleDB.sqlite");
    db.CreateTable<Person>();

    db.Insert(new Person(ID_PERSON, NAME_PERSON));
```

Is there any way, to use the old way (as in windows forms) in Universal Windows app?
IE:

```
    //Instead of using this:
    db.Insert(new Person(ID_PERSON, NAME_PERSON));
    //I want to use this:
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("insert into Person ...", conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is using [Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/), which supports Sql Query String like what you've used in Windows Forms. We can use this library instead of SQLite.Net-PCL.

To use this library, we can install it form [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/) and then use it like following:

```cs
using (var connection = new SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection("sampleDB.sqlite"))
{
    using (var statement = connection.Prepare(@"select * from Person"))
    {
        while (statement.Step() == SQLitePCL.SQLiteResult.ROW)
        {
            //TODO. For example
            //Gets the value of the specified column by the column name.
            var Id = (long)(statement["Id"]);
            var Name = (string)statement["Name"];

            //Gets the value of the specified column by the column ordinal.
            //var Id = (long)(statement[0]);
            //var Name = (string)statement[1];
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to this blog: [The new Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/the-new-portable-class-library-for-sqlite/). Although this article is for Windows 8.1, but it also applies to UWP apps.

Comment: Can you please also add in the TODO part how would you use let's say Name attribute from table Person?

Comment: i.e. before I used reader["Name"] to get that attribute. How do I use it now?

Comment: @MihaJamsek To read the records returned by the query, we need to iterate through the rows, in a way that resembles the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) Class. Here we can get the value of the specified column either by the the column ordinal or  the column name. As this method gets a result of `Object` type, you may need to cast it to the real type of the column. For example, please see my updated answer.